# How do I transpile React JSX and ES6 modules with babel and use browser native ES6

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs, reactjs, es6-modules

The problem I have is when using the "react-app" Babel presets, Babel prevents me from using browser native ES6 features.

How do I use the **ES6 browser native features** available in the latest Chrome
http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

While also using the **ES6 module system**, which currently has no support
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

And additionally **keep using the JSX syntax** while writing React Components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I found was to do the following.

Create a .babelrc file
Then use the settings below

```js
{
    "presets": ["react"],
    "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-umd"]
}
```

The presets react setting loads the modules that handles the JSX transpilation
https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/

The transfrom es2015 modules umd setting handles the modules system.
https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-modules-umd/